# How to use ng-view inside jsp?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, ng-view

My conditions:

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSm9W.png)

1. MainController correctly serves Index.jsp.
2. Index.jsp correctly connects to main.js.
3. main.js does not inject "inner/home.html" into ng-view.

**Why is "inner/home.html" not injected?**

Controller:

```
package com.treeweb.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by bluecastle on 8-12-16.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "Index";
    }
}
```

Index.jsp:

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: bluecastle
  Date: 8-12-16
  Time: 8:49
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html ng-app="treeApp">
<head>
    <title>Treeweb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angularjs</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="main">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/main.js' />"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```js
var treeApp = angular.module('treeApp', ['ngRoute']);

treeApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    // implementations to be made
});

treeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'inner/home.html',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: No errors. inner/home.html is just not being injected.